# AWS SES Custom Verification Email Redirect URL has no params

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I need to verify email addresses for my customers so that I can send emails on their behalf. AWS SES has a sender verification feature where you need to send the email address in the request body and SES will send a verification email on that email address with a confirmation link.

[image]

We can also configure redirection URLs for success and failure while setting up a custom email template.

[image]

The issue is that I'm not getting any parameters when it redirects to my custom URL. I need at least the email_id in the redirected URL params so that I can mark the email verified in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no option to pass any query parameter on the redirect URL. For now, I see two possible solutions:

1. > [...] you can create different customized verification email templates for
   >   different email addresses you're attempting to verify, each using its
   >   own success redirect link (e.g. with the additional query string
   >   appended) [...]

[Answer to the same question in AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=818836&#818836)

2. Fetching identity verification status using `GetIdentityVerificationAttributes`. You can create lambda function that runs once every 5 mins and calls for all identity verifications, then filter by status *Success* and update your app according to it.
   [AWS documentation for GetIdentityVerificationAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_GetIdentityVerificationAttributes.html)